# Inkwell in MaterialApp not found

Tags: flutter

I'am getting the following error when i attempt to use Inkwell

```
No Material widget found.
InkWell widgets require a Material widget ancestor.
In material design, ....
The specific widget that could not find a Material ancestor was:
  InkWell

The ancestors of this widget were:
  ...
  Column
  TextOnCanvasWidget
  RepaintBoundary
  IndexedSemantics
  NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification>
  ...

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  InkWell
```

I know that i need to use Material design as an ancestor to use inkwell... but i think i am...

However, it shows in the trace that my ancestry tree is Column->TextOnCanvasWidget->RepaintBoundary..

I guess i am confused why my material widget is not shown in my ancestry tree when my top module is MaterialApp.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: TextOnCanvasList(),
    );
  }
}

class TextOnCanvasList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> listOfNames = [
    "Matt",
    "John",
    "Bill123456",
    "Doug",
    "Paul",
    "Hanz",
    "Ruby",
    "Karl",
    "WOW123456789",
    "HAL",
    "TODD",
    "MARK",
    "CURT"
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        reverse: false,
        itemBuilder: (_, int index) =>
            TextOnCanvasWidget(this.listOfNames[index]),
        itemCount: listOfNames.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TextOnCanvasWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  TextOnCanvasWidget(this.name);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            print("You Tapped: " + this.name);
          },
          child: new CustomPaint(
            size: Size(52, 0),
            foregroundPainter: new TextOnCanvasPainter(this.name),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class TextOnCanvasPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final String name;
  TextOnCanvasPainter(this.name);
  static const l0 = 50.0;
  static final l1 = 10.0;
  static final h = 30.0;
  final Path chevron = new Path()
    ..relativeLineTo(l0, 0)
    ..relativeLineTo(l1, h / 2)
    ..relativeLineTo(-l1, h / 2)
    ..relativeLineTo(-l0, 0)
    ..relativeLineTo(l1, -h / 2)
    ..close();
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint fillShape = new Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0;
    TextSpan span = new TextSpan(
      style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.red[600]),
      text: this.name,
    );
    TextPainter tp = new TextPainter(
        text: span,
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
    tp.layout(minWidth: 500.0);
    canvas.drawPath(chevron, fillShape);
    tp.paint(canvas, new Offset(l1, h / 8));
    canvas.save();
    canvas.restore();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(TextOnCanvasPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Comment: Wrap your `InkWell` in `Material` widget then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are missing Scaffold. Wrap SafeArea in `Scaffold` and that error will be gone.

Comment: That worked.... i still don't understand why i have to use scaffold.... i dont see that mentioned in the documentation for inkwell

Comment: @user254340 Scaffold is what defines the structure of a "page" or "screen". In Flutter, all the widgets you see need to be displayed on a page or screen. Whenever you want to show a page or want to move to another page like by clicking on a button, you use Scaffold. [Read this](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/know-your-widgets-scaffold-in-flutter-292b8bc1281) for detailed explanation on Scaffold.